# What is the graph width?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a problem like this:

> An undirected graph $G$ has width $w$ if the vertices can be arranged in a sequence $v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n$ such that each vertex $v_i$ is joined by an edge to at most $w$ preceding vertices. (Vertex $v_j$ precedes $v_i$ if $j$ < $i$.) Use induction to prove that every graph with width at most $w$ is $(w + 1)$-colorable.

*[Source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/recitations/MIT6_042JF10_rec06.pdf)*

I think I could do the proof in general, but before that, I would need to understand what graph width is. My problem is, I can't really visualize how a graph that satisfies the property from above (the vertices can be arranged in the given sequence) would look like. I also read the definition of [Treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth), but it wasn't clear for me if that's even the same thing as in the problem.

How would a graph look like that satisfies the property from the problem description?

Comment: A graph of width $w$ is one you can draw this way: Draw a vertex $v_1,$ then draw a vertex $v_2,$ then draw edges joining $v_2$ to at most $w$ of the previously drawn vertices, then draw a vertex $v_3$ and edges joining $v_3$ to at most $w$ of the previous vertices, and so on. In other words, exactly what the definition says. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some intuition as to why it's called *width*.

Think of vertices as cities and edges as lanes. Say a $v_j$ is a *larger* city than $v_i$ if $j>i$.

You want to get from $v_n$ to $v_1$ and never want to travel from a city to a larger one. That is, during your journey, you always want to travel to a smaller city from the one you are currently in.

Now, the statement that the graph has *width* *w* means that at every leg of your journey, you have at most $w$ roads to choose from. If edges are lanes, the width is the maximum number of lanes connecting a city to all cities smaller than it.

So $w$ basically *bounds the number of choices* you have at each stage.

Why does this relate to colouring? 
Hint:

> Think choices. Start colouring from $v_1$ to $v_n$ and while colouring $v_k$ see how many choices we have while going to a smaller city.

Comment: I didn't know it was called *width*, I thought it was called *degeneracy*.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)) says "Degeneracy is also known as the k-core number, width, and linkage, and is essentially the same as the coloring number or Szekeres-Wilf number "

Comment: Thank you that is a great example and helped me visualizing how such a graph looked like.