# Proof - k-degenerate graph with width w is colorable in w+1 colors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory

The problem states:

> An undirected graph $G$ has width $w$ if the vertices can be arranged in a sequence $v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n$ such that each vertex $v_i$ is joined by an edge to at most $w$ preceding vertices. (Vertex $v_j$ precedes $v_i$ if $j$ < $i$.) Use induction to prove that every graph with width at most $w$ is $(w + 1)$-colorable.

*[Source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/recitations/MIT6_042JF10_rec06.pdf)*

My proof is also a [follow up](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403257/what-is-the-graph-width), as I first had to learn about the general concept of graph width (or degeneracy).

The problem set also has a solution for this proof, but I wanted to formulate it in my own words and wanted to check if I got it right.

---

Proposition: Every graph with width $w$ is colorable in $w+1$ colors. We proceed by proof by induction, we induct on $n$, the number of nodes in a graph.

Basecase, $P(1)$ - graph $G$ contains only one vertex, so it has width $w = 0$, so $G$ can be colored in $w + 1 = 1$ colors.

Inductive step $P(n + 1)$ - we may assume $P(n)$, that is, a graph with width $w$ can be colored in $w + 1$ colors.

Assume we have a graph $G$ with $n + 1$ vertices and width $w$. These vertices can be arranged in an order $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n, v_{n+1}$, such that every vertex $v_i$ is connected by an edge to at most $w$ preceeding vertices.

By removing $v_{n+1}$ and all it's edges from $G$, we are left with a subgraph $G'$ that has $n$ vertices and has width $w$. $w$ can't increase in $G'$ since $v_{n+1}$ is the last vertex in the list of vertices and can be connected to at most $w$ preceeding vertices. Therefore we can assume that $G'$ can be colored in at most $w+1$ colors, as per $P(n)$.

Now we add $v_{n+1}$ and all its edges back to $G'$ and get $G$ again. Since $v_{n+1}$ can be connected to at most $w$ preceeding nodes, we can color $G$ using $w + 1$ colors.

---

Does the proof make sense? I had a bit issues explaining why it's important to only remove $v_{n+1}$ and not any node at random, I think.

Comment: I think the proof looks fine. It might be more clear to say that once you add $v_{n+1}$, there is at least one color $v_{n+1}$ is not adjacent to, but that's just a teeny nitpick. Nice job!